# Calculating the value of a mathematical function in Java

Tags: java, math, algebra

I have this function and I was trying to get a list of all the calculations.

```
f(x) = (100)(1.1)^X
```

How do I calculate this out in Java. I tried a for loop to get the value of x and the end result of y, but that didn't work. Might have been my code inside. I tried to get the exponent of 1.1 and the multiply that by 100, is this correct?

```
for(int i = 1; i<=15; i++){
     int expcalc = (int) Math.pow(1.1, i);
     int finalcalc = price * expcalc;
     System.out.println(" " + finalcalc);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you truncating the results to a integer value?  Where is price?  What exactly is the problem?  You don't specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you casting the result as an `int`?  That will drop everything past the decimal point.  Declare `expcalc` and `finalcalc` as `double` instead to obtain an accurate result.

```
double expcalc = Math.pow(1.1, i);
double finalcalc = price * expcalc;
```

Comment: Lol, thanks. I honestly don't know how I didn't even think of using double.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you're using pow() and decimal values, and ESPECIALLY ON **MONEY**

Assuming your interpretation is correct,

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("0.0"); //change this value to your price
for(int i = 1; i<=15; i++){
    BigDecimal expcalc = new BigDecimal("1.1").pow(i);
    BigDecimal finalcalc = price.multiply(expcalc);
    System.out.println(" " + finalcalc);
}
```

Avoid using double/float on monetary computations.